# start service multiple times with different intents

Tags: android, service

lets say we have two buttons:

First  button:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
i.putExtra("url","https://api.crowdscores.com/api/v1/matches/53102")
startService(i);
```

second button :

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,MyService.class);
    i.putExtra("url","https://api.crowdscores.com/api/v1/matches/53113");
    startService(i);
```

on MyService i have a timer which retrieve data every 30 seconds for about 2 hours long

when i click button can't start the other one but first service is finished(Destroyed)

how can i run the two services in parallel ?

Comment: You cannot run two instances of one service.

Comment: what can i use to solve this problem ?

Comment: You should probably use IntentService

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't run them in Parallel.  The Android API handles this for you.  If the service isn't running the first time you call `startService()`, then its `onCreate()` method is called. However, if it is running, then that results in a call to the service's `onStartCommand()`.

> Multiple requests to start the service result in multiple corresponding calls to the service's onStartCommand().

It's up to you to handle the logic to create a thread for each request to run that service.  Take a look at this overview of how to accomplish your task:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService

That will walk you through creating your service correctly, allowing you to send multiple requests simultaneously.